# Modified JSON response from nestjs while creating API

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs

I do have json like below

[
[{

```
                        "id": "4e181c1b-0a68-425e-9eb7-df36324b6cdb",
                        "date_actual": {
                            "value": "2020-10-21T13:15:00"
                        },
                        "Date": "20201021",
                        "name": "abc"
            
            
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "4e181c1b-0a68-425e-9eb7-df36324qqq",
                        "date_actual": {
                            "value": "2020-1-21T13:15:00"
                        },
                        "Date": "2020102",
                        "name": "xyz"
            
                    }
                ]
            ]
```

want to modified like below

[
{
"id": "4e181c1b-0a68-425e-9eb7-df36324b6cdb",
"date_actual": "2020-10-21T13:15:00",
"Date": "20201021",
"name": "abc"

```
             },
            
            {
                "id": "4e181c1b-0a68-425e-9eb7-df36324qqq",
                "date_actual": "2020-10-21T13:15:00",
                "Date": "2020102",
                "name": "xyz"
           }
            ]
```

My service class code is

```
const rows = await bigqueryClient.query(queryData);
console.log("old json"+JSON.stringify(rows));
return rows;
```

how to solve this issue using nestjs  any way please help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't specific to NodeJS or NestJS, but is regular old JavaScript. As you have an array of values you can use the `Array.prototype.map` method to map to a new array

```js
return origArray.map((val) => ({ ...val, date_actual: val.date_actual.value }))
```

Comment: This is my servcie class code  how I will apply code which you provide ?   const rows = await bigqueryClient.query(queryData);
    console.log("old json"+JSON.stringify(rows));
    return rows;

Comment: In the code snippet I provided, use `rows` instead of `origArray`. Please read up on basic JavaScript code practices. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/javascript), [Tutorial Points](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/index.htm), and [W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/DEFAULT.asp) are three great beginner resources.